# SpriteKit class separation issue

Tags: class, sprite-kit

I have a property named ball with two functions - setup() and launch():

```
var ball = Ball()
```

After I call ball.launch() I'd like to know where it is on the x-axis using:

```
ball.position.x
```

But for some reason, I keep getting zero. Right now, I'm launching the ball from `touchesBegan` and trying to get the position in `touchesEnded`. As I said, the launching part works fine. The ball appears, and it bounces around as expected, but nothing I do the the ball property has any effect after that point. Here is the complete code:

Ball.swift

```
class Ball: SKSpriteNode {

    var ball: SKSpriteNode!

    func setUp(parentNode: SKNode) {

        ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball2")
        ball.name = "ball"
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 200)
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.width / 2)
        ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Ball
        ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Edge
        ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Edge
        parentNode.addChild(ball)
    }


    func launch() {
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 25, dy: 0))
    }

}
```

GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

struct PhysicsCategories {

    static let Ball:     UInt32 = 0
    static let Edge:     UInt32 = 0b1
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var ball = Ball()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        border.friction = 0
        border.restitution = 1
        physicsBody = border
        border.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Edge
        border.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Ball
        border.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Ball

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        ball.setUp(parentNode: self)
        ball.launch()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print(ball.position.x) //value is always zero
    }


    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let collision = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        switch collision {
        case PhysicsCategories.Ball | PhysicsCategories.Edge:
            ball.removeFromParent() //doesn't get removed
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the wrong property. You are creating a `Ball` in your gamescene.swift, but do nothing with it except call `launch()`, but `launch()` only affects *ball.ball*, because you have created *two* ball properties.

The ball you created in your gamescene is never added to the scene and never does anything, hence why it shows that your position never changes.

To rectify this, you want to use the `Ball` class as a *blueprint* for creating *ball properties* by your gamescene.

```
class Ball: SKSpriteNode {

  // You don't want to create an object of the type you are creating here...
  // as a property of the class!:
  // var ball: SKSpriteNode!

  func setUp(parentNode: SKNode) {

    self.name = "ball"
    self.position = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 200)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.width / 2)
    self.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    self.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Ball
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Edge
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Edge
    self.parentNode.addChild(ball)
  }


  func launch() {
    self.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 25, dy: 0))
  }

}
```

Now when you call `ball.launch()`, the state you are actually modifying is `ball`, not `ball.ball` (because I deleted ball.ball and changed it to `self` =} )

Here is a simple representation of what you are doing, and why it isn't working as expected:

```
class Cat {

 var fluffy: Cat!

  var name = "no name"

  func changeName() {
    fluffy = Cat()
    fluffy.name = "Fluffy"
  }

}

var fluffy = Cat()
fluffy.changeName()
print(fluffy.name) // no name
print(fluffy.fluffy.name) // Fluffy
```